# Позиционирование элемента относительно блока по координатам

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, позиционирование

Привет.

Имеется такое построение checkbox-ов на сайте:

```
<li>
    <label class="cb-input">
        <input class="cb-input__checkbox" type="checkbox">
        <span class="cb-input__check"></span>
        <span class="cb-input__label">Calipso</span>
    </label>
    <label class="found-items"></label>
</li>
```

При наведении на элемент списка должен появляться `<label class="found-items"></label>` где отображено количество найденных товаров, проблема в том что спаны с текстом имеют разную ширину (в зависимости от количества символов).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** как можно сделать при помощи Jquery/Vanila чтобы данный элемент выводился относительно ширины `<span class="cb-input__label">Calipso</span>` спана с текстом?

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть стили и работающий пример, чтобы лучше понять проблему.

Comment: Что значит относительно ширины? Зачем вам label еще рядом один? Засуньте это "Найдено" в первый `label`, ему `position:relative;` а вплывашка тогда будет относительно текста стоять.

Answer (score 1):

Скрытие и показ элемента при наведении можно реализовать используя только CSS. А JS, в данном случае, нужен лишь для подстановки значения в этот элемент.

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #3e77c7;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.cb-input {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.found-items {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px currentcolor;
}

.found-items::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em;
  transform: translatex(calc(-50% + 1px)) rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 0 currentcolor;
}

/* Если нужна реакция для всей ширины LI,
   тогда раскомментируйте строку ниже  */
/* li:hover > .found-items, */
.cb-input:hover+.found-items {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label class="cb-input">
      <input class="cb-input__checkbox" type="checkbox">
      <span class="cb-input__check"></span>
      <span class="cb-input__label">Calipso</span>
    </label>
    <label class="found-items">Найдено 8</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="cb-input">
      <input class="cb-input__checkbox" type="checkbox">
      <span class="cb-input__check"></span>
      <span class="cb-input__label">Titan Atlas</span>
    </label>
    <label class="found-items">Найдено 573</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="cb-input">
      <input class="cb-input__checkbox" type="checkbox">
      <span class="cb-input__check"></span>
      <span class="cb-input__label">Hyas</span>
    </label>
    <label class="found-items">Найдено 89</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```